# How do I get a usable colour scheme for Windows 8? (more like Windows XP)

Tags: windows-8, themes

On Windows XP (and earlier) there was a difference between dialog background and input fields: The former were a shade of gray, the latter where white. On Windows 8 there seems to be no option to change these two colours independently. Is there any way to switch back to that old look? Or maybe even an existing theme that gives me back the old look?[image]

Edit: Added screenshot

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of the dialog box?

Comment: You can set Windows 8 to use a Windows XP theme.

Comment: @Ramhound: How do I do that? In personalization I only get 3 Windows Default Themes and 4 High Contras Themes. Then there is the Option "Get more themes online" which takes me to a web page with thousands of themes, none of them looking like Windows XP.

Comment: @dummzeuch - Looking into the problem in more detail it appears that "Windows Classic" is the best you will get.  Most of visuals that would exists within a Windows XP theme no longer exist within Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called "Windows Classic Theme for Windows 8 RTM" available from [deviantart](http://kizo2703.deviantart.com/art/Windows-classic-theme-for-Windows-8-RTM-325642288) It looks much better than the available default themes but is not quite what I was looking for. Good enough for now, though. Thanks to Ramhound who pointed me in that direction.

http://kizo2703.deviantart.com/art/Windows-classic-theme-for-Windows-8-RTM-325642288